# Sigma-algebra of a dice

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question about sigma-algebra. I have a 6-sided dice with Omega = {1...6} and I want to determine the sigma-algebra of it.

So i added the empty set omega; each value and the complements:

> {0,Omega,{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{23456},{13456},{12456},{12356},{12346},{12345}}

So the actual question is do need to add all combinations and there compliments to be a valid sigma-algebra?
for example:

```
12,13,14,15,16,3456,2456...
123,134,...
...
```

and so on?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Since the base set "Omega" (see [introduction to math formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)) or $\Omega$ is finite, the $\sigma$-algebra is the same as the Boolean algebra with atoms in $\Omega$.  Thus the generated algebra will consist of all subsets of $\Omega$ and have $2^6 = 64$ such subsets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there isn't THE $\sigma$-algebra of a set $\Omega$ . For example is $A := \{\emptyset, \Omega \}$ already a $\sigma$-algebra of $\Omega$.

Second, for your question, yes the $\sigma$-algebra has to be closed under countable union of sets in it, so if you want your $\sigma$-algebra to contain every singleton of the elements in $\Omega$, then it has to be the whole power set of $\Omega$.